# How to store multiple values of HTML dropdownlist into array and seperate them by comma using PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-select, dropdownlistfor

I want to store 4 values of this dropdownlist into an array using PHP, and I also want to separate them by comma and save them into different single variable.

```
<td>
    <select name="Ty" size=4 multiple>
        <option value="Action">Action</option>
        <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
        <option value="Animation">Animation</option>
        <option value="Bollywood">Bollywood</option>
        <option value="Marathi">Marathi</option>
        <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
        <option value="crime">Crime</option>
        <option value="Documentary">Documentary</option>
        <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
        <option value="Family">Family</option>
        <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
        <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
        <option value="Sci">Sci-Fi</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Wrap a form around that control, and look at the variable `$_POST['Ty]` to see what it contains. Change your attributes so `size="4"` - if you miss the quotes your HTML document is invalid. Not sure what the rules are for `multiple` - check the HTML5 documentation - it's invalid for XHTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Putting values into an array

Replace

```
<select name="Ty" size=4 multiple>
```

With

```
<select name="Ty[]" size=4 multiple>
```

#### Separate the values by a comma

In the page the form points to, insert this code

```
<?php
$count = count($_POST['Ty']); //number of elements in the array
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$allvalues .= $_POST['Ty'][$i];
$minus = $count-1;
if($i<$minus){$allvalues .= ',';} //prevents to add a comma also to the last element of the array
}
echo $allvalues;
?>
```

#### Saving values into different variables

Not sure what you're exactly meaning with this. If I understood well, you could use something like this

```
$var1 = $_POST['Ty'][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$_POST['Ty']` is an array you can convert it into a single comma separated string like this:

```
$comma_separated = implode(',',$_POST['Ty']);
```